# How to check that web page is loaded 100 percent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, html

Is there any way to check that, web page is loaded 100 percent in javascript?

100 percent means all the images,files,scripts,styles everything that a web page contains.

Comment: `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: `$(window).load()` event is fired when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: Please clarify. What does 100% mean. Only the page? Also styles? images? the contents of all iFrames?

Comment: Also, you are asking how to do this in javascript but you also have a jquery tag. Are you looking for jquery or javascript code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `window.onload` function for that. E.g.

```
window.onload = function () { alert("It's loaded!") }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
if (document.readyState === "complete") {

}
```

That it what you need to check if the page is loaded for 100%.

If you want to trigger a function after the DOM Content is loaded, use:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  
});
```

Comment: Doesn't wait for anything but the DOM. Please note the question was updated.

Comment: @JanDvorak He didn't ask for a code that would wait for the document to fully load, he asked for a way to check if the page loaded. Which can be done with `if (document.readyState === "complete") { }`. Please read the question before downvoting my answer. Also, if the `document.readyState` is set to `complete` it means everything is loaded (100%).

Comment: Removed my vote because you removed `$(document).ready`. That second part indeed wasn't what the asker wanted.

Comment: can we get the percentage of resources loaded? like images,scripts etc etc?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, window.onload:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // web page is loaded
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with 100% ?

You can verifiy that DOM is fully loaded with `<body onreadystatechange="functionCalled();">`
Or with jQuery syntax : `$(document).ready(function() {});`

But it won't wait for images, for instance.

***EDIT***

And if you want to check the readystate of dynamically loaded content, you still can use `.ready` method of jQuery. But you have to use it on the selector of what you load, not on body or window, or document.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  ready=true;
  $('img,link').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).load(function() {
      ready=false;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: 100 percent means => all the images , files , scripts are loaded!!

Comment: @DixitSingla, use `$(window).load()`

Comment: @DixitSingla please clarify that in the question, not as a comment to one of the answers

Comment: `$().ready` ignores its argument...

Comment: Why `$(this).load` every element separately, rather than the whole document?

Comment: In case of dynamycally loaded contents ...
And you can know which elements is not ready. Instead of just know that everything is not loaded ...